# What is the equivalent of DynamicQueryable in System.Linq.Dynamic.Core?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic

I am migrating some C# code from NuGet's System.Linq.Dynamic package to System.Linq.Dynamic.Core because the former is no longer supported.  The code made use of  System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable like so:

```
IQueryable<RoomAssignmentDateInfo> consecutiveResidencyQuery = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(otherResidencyQuery, string.Join(" or ", predicateBatch.ToArray()), parmBatch.ToArray());
```

DynamicQueryable does not appear to be represented in System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.  What do I replace it with?

Comment: Never heard of DynamicQueryable. Can you describe what the result of the LINQ Query should be?

Comment: System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions ?

Comment: @sgmoore Your suggestion compiles.  Please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions can be used to replace System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable as @sgmoore suggested.